# Cycle through divs with up/down arrow in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this row of divs that are clickable to display different output to the user. When these div's are clicked, it runs different functions accordingly.

```
<div class="modeHolder" id="visionButtons">

        <button class="modeButton" id="fourHundred" onclick="oneLetter(this); win2.increment400();">20/400</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="threeHundred" onclick="oneLetter(this); win2.increment300();">20/300</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="twoHundred" onclick="twoLetter(this); win2.increment200();">20/200</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="oneHundred" onclick="threeLetter(this); win2.increment100();">20/100</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="eighty" onclick="fourLetter(this); win2.increment80();">20/80</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="seventy" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment70();">20/70</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="sixty" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment60();">20/60</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="fifty" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment50();">20/50</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="forty" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment40();">20/40</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="thirty" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment30();">20/30</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="twentyFive" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment25();">20/25</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="twenty" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment20();">20/20</button>


    </div>
```

I have searched through stackoverflow, and i found an answer a few weeks ago but it was at work and i forgot to bookmark it and i can't find it again. I basically want to cycle through these with up/down arrow keys. If the user is on 20/30 and presses "up", i want the active focus to go the 20/40 div. Once it reaches the top or bottom, it doesn't have to cycle back around. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm ok with any answer that would work, javascript/jquery, anything.

Comment: First of, you have a series of `<button>` s, not DIVs

Comment: noted. apologies for the mis-label.

Comment: Your question is still incomprehensible. Please create a [mcve]. I'm 100% sure your code can be simplified drastically. Hard to say without a "working" example.

Comment: for a working example go to www.truvisionacuity.com/sandbox.html . this is already a working application. i'm trying to add a new feature of functionality to it

Comment: link not found. You should place the minimal necessary code in your question, not point StackOverflow visitors to dead or expired links.

Comment: ok....dude, cool out. the link is not expired, please click it again. i just went there myself and it is very much active

Comment: i thought this code would be sufficient for what i was looking for. it has my classes and id's. i just want to cycle through them and apply an active class to the one on top or below depending on the keypress.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan here is a codepen of the concept. another stack overflow user contributed to it. it's almost there. it cycles through the buttons but a spacebar is required to activate it. the "cycle" code is found at the very bottom of the javascript pane. do you have any idea how to make it so that a space bar is not required to activate the code? where it can just run when the arrows are hit? codepen.io/maxbourque1127/pen/NYpjEo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function(){
  //get the buttons, make it an array
  var modeButtons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.modeButton'));
  
  function focusOnAdjacentElement (e) {
    //get the keycode
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    
    //is it up or down?
    if ([38, 40].indexOf(code) > -1) {
      //if it is up, subtract one, otherwise add one
      var adjustment = (code == 38 ? -1 : 1);
      var nextIndex = (modeButtons.indexOf(e.target) + adjustment);
      
      //get min so we don't go outside the bottom bounds
      nextIndex = Math.min(nextIndex, modeButtons.length - 1);
      //get max so we do not go < 0
      nextIndex = Math.max(nextIndex, 0);
      //adjust the focus
      modeButtons[nextIndex].focus();
    }
  }
  
  modeButtons.forEach(element => element.addEventListener( 'keyup', focusOnAdjacentElement));
  
  modeButtons[0].focus();
}());
```

```html
<div class="modeHolder" id="visionButtons">

        <button class="modeButton" id="fourHundred" onclick="oneLetter(this); win2.increment400();">20/400</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="threeHundred" onclick="oneLetter(this); win2.increment300();">20/300</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="twoHundred" onclick="twoLetter(this); win2.increment200();">20/200</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="oneHundred" onclick="threeLetter(this); win2.increment100();">20/100</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="eighty" onclick="fourLetter(this); win2.increment80();">20/80</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="seventy" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment70();">20/70</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="sixty" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment60();">20/60</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="fifty" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment50();">20/50</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="forty" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment40();">20/40</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="thirty" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment30();">20/30</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="twentyFive" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment25();">20/25</button>
        <button class="modeButton" id="twenty" onclick="fiveLetter(this); win2.increment20();">20/20</button>


    </div>
```

Comment: taplar, you are the man(/woman/person). your code looks solid as heck. i just copied it into my file but i'm not sure exactly how to apply it. i pasted it at the bottom of my javascript section (using internal javascript, not an external file) but it doesn't have the desired result. do i need to name the parent function or call it on each button some kind of way?

Comment: The outer most function is an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Functional Expression).  I just used that to provide a name space.  If you don't want that, you can take the logic out of it.

Comment: ok. i just removed the outer most function and it's still not cycling the buttons. would you prefer me to give you the entire code so you can examine it? it's a rather long file.

Comment: Try putting a console.log as the first statement in the event handler and see if you see it print out anything on the arrow up and down.  Also verify that a button has focus on your page when you do this as if none of them have focus the event handler will not fire.

Comment: please don't get frustrated with me for asking seemingly simple questions...i'm coming from a world of php and trying to tackle a javascript project.......what event handler are you talking about?

Comment: Nah, it's cool.  See the `element.addEventListener( 'keyup', focusOnAdjacentElement)` part?  That's creating an event listener for the keyup event on those elements.  The function that you give it, `focusOnAdjacentElement` in this case, is the event handler.  It's what processes ("handles") the event when it happens on the element.

Comment: ok so would my console.log look like this? modeButtons.forEach(element => element.addEventListener( 'keyup', console.log));

Comment: ok, that was right apparently. I am getting the correct keycodes each time i press an up or down arrow key in the console. so what am i missing then?

Comment: Not sure.  You could try logging the `nextIndex` and see if it is accurate, and if it changes.  Heads up, i'm fixing to head out of work for the day, but if the question is still open tomorrow i'll try to check in if it's still unresolved.

Comment: ok. thanks for the help mate. i'll create a code pen here and post it in just a second. i greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the KeyDown event on the parent div.

Now just trigger click on the previous or next element by using next() or prev()

$(this).prev().trigger('click');

Comment: ok, i see your edit for the prev() trigger. how do i plug in the keydown event? i apologize for the noob questions but i'm not incredibly familiar with javascript as a whole